# "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'

Tags: c#, linq, dynamicquery

I was using the same query before it was working fine. Then I decided to use complied query. So I had to make few changes to the code.

Now when I try to execute the code, I get the error message "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Where'. 
The where clause which I generate from  “approvalHelper.GetWhereClauseForApprovalSimpleSearch();” has been tested and works fine.
Only doesn't work for the complied query part as shown in my code

## code :

```
// Complied Query Class
public static class CompliedQuery
{

    public static Func<GDataContext, Expression<Func<View_ApprovalSimple, bool>>, IQueryable<View_ApprovalSimple>> getApprovalSimple =


    CompiledQuery.Compile<GDataContext, Expression<Func<View_ApprovalSimple, bool>>, IQueryable<View_ApprovalSimple>>(
           (db, whereclause) => (from results in db.View_ApprovalSimples.AsExpandable().Where(whereclause)
                                select results));        
}

// this is what is passed into the where clause; Body = {(vas.siteId = 1)}


//the Calling code
public static List<View_ApprovalSimple> GetApprovalSimple(ApprovalsSearchHelperClass _approvalHelper)
{
    Expression<Func<View_ApprovalSimple, bool>> whrClause = approvalHelper.GetWhereClauseForApprovalSimpleSearch();

    //whrclause; Body = {(vas.siteId = 1)}
    try
    {
        using (GDataContext db = new GDataContext())
        {
            if (whrClause != null)
            {
                var varResults = CompliedQuery.getApprovalSimple(db, whrClause);

                return varResults.ToList();
            }
        }  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // code to handle error        
    }
    finally
    {          
    }

    return null;    
}
```

Any idea what new changes I might have to implement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I was a bit sceptical about this, ran out of options so I finally tried it and it did work.
please follow the link to see answer
[Steve's Blog](http://srstrong.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/passing-predicates-into-compiled.html)
Great work Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespaces (start off by copying them all from `CompliedQuery`) to the calling class.